# how to define object field name from a string variable ><

Tags: javascript

```
var car = {
  name: "roll_royce",
  add: [
    { color: "red", location: "USA_1" },
    { color: "green", location: "USA_2" },
  ],
  pay: { type: { name: "USD" } },
};
```

I want to write a function like this:

```
getCar(car, 'add.0.location') // USA_1, same as car.add[0].location 
getCar(car, 'pay.type') // USD, same as car.pay.type
```

But I can't use car."string". how to solve it.
thanks advance ...

Comment: Try using Lodash ~ https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Comment: BTW, `pay.type` won't be `USD`, instead it would be `{ name: 'USD' }`

Comment: @Phil why to use lodash when this problem can easily solved by `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: @decpk that's all well and good until one of those iterations returns `undefined`. Anyway, Lodash was just a suggestion with a robust and well tested solution

Comment: @Phil very true but can handle it using `acc[curr] ?? {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce`.

```js
var car = {
  name: "roll_royce",
  add: [
    { color: "red", location: "USA_1" },
    { color: "green", location: "USA_2" },
  ],
  pay: { type: { name: "USD" } },
};
function getCar(obj, props){
  return props.split('.').reduce((a, b)=>a?.[b], obj);
}
console.log(getCar(car, 'add.0.location'));
console.log(getCar(car, 'pay.type'));
```

Comment: Does this question deserve an answer, OP hasn't shown any research and even gave a try.

Comment: use `a[b] ?? {}` to cover the `undefined` case i.e. `"pay.type.a.b"`. BTW I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @decpk I also closed this as a duplicate 1 minute before this answer

Comment: @decpk Although it wasn't mentioned in the question, `a?.[b]` covers that case.